# Android studio - unwanted tab dragging

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an EXTREMELY annoying problem with Android Studio. Scenario:

1) Switch tabs by clicking on a tab;

2) First action in the new tab is to highlight some code via the mouse.

In some cases dragging the mouse after the left click drags the tab as if I'd clicked on the tab and wanted to reposition it.

I have not been able to discern any pattern to the phenomenon; for example, the time between switching tabs and the left click, the position of the left click.

Any suggestions as to how to stop this?

Comment: Same issue.  I'd love to figure out how to make this stop.